# How to get the JSON String from the Javascript object (Visualforce page displays as [OBJECT,OBJECT]

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I have a JSON data that I am trying to send it to the Visualforce page from the Lighting component. I would like to know how can I get the JSON displayed as a string so that I can display the values from the JSON on the VF Page.

**Lighting Component code :**

```
handleRowAction: function (cmp, event) {
  var action = event.getParam('action');
  //var item = event.getParam('row');
  var item = '{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "car": "HONDA",
    "Confirmation": 123456
            }';
        switch (action.name) {
            case 'demo_PDF':
            var baseUrl= decodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
            var url = ' https://'+baseUrl+'/apex/DemoPdf?pdfDetails='+item;
                window.open(url);
                break;
        }
```

**Apex Class:**

```
    public class PDFController {

        public String jsonString {get;set;}

        public PDFController() {
            this.jsonString = (string)System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('pdfDetails');
            system.debug('ResponseData passed to VF Page'+ this.jsonString);
            Map<string,object> reponse = ( Map<string,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

            system.debug('ResponseData passed to VF Page'+reponse);
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="PDFController" renderAs="pdf">
    <html>
        <p>
            {!jsonString}
        </p>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create javascript object instead of string in lightning component then convert in to string by using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). i just tested VF page opens and gives data like image.
[image]

```
var item = {
"name": "John",
"age": 30,
"car": "HONDA",
"Confirmation": 123456
        };
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'demo_PDF':
        var baseUrl= decodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
        var url = ' https://'+baseUrl+'/apex/DemoPdf?pdfDetails='+JSON.stringify(item);
            window.open(url);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Hi sdandamudi, Thanks for your reply, but I am looking to pass a JSON object as a parameter as I have a very large JSON Values to consume (Cannot send as URL Parameters) to show on  PDF. In the example above was just a sample where I took a small JSON. I would like to know how to send the JSON object to VF and deserialize in the Apex controller and display the values on the VF                                                    
var URL = ' https://'+baseUrl+'/apex/DemoPdf?pdfDetails='+item;

Comment: @Donald, Hi Donald, did you manage to convert the JSON object passed to VF and deserialize in the Apex controller.I am stuck in there

Answer (score 1):

why not use remote action from a VF page to call an apex controller method (JavaScript remoting ) in that way you can return a object as result to your java script function

Refer below article

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm